# Text Input Fields from markdown and Pandoc

Tags: pandoc, markdown

I'd like to use markdown and pandoc to create a document where I have some text input. Is it possible to specify fields that, when the pdf is generated, would appear as text input?

Answer (score 3):

You can use all the tools provided by hyperref (cf. section 6 of the [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/hyperref/manual.pdf)) such as `\TextField`:

```
# Section 1

\TextField[name=Field1, width=\hsize]{Input here:}
```

Which gives you a form like this:

[image]